# jQuery Animate Rotate and scroll text fast in middle but slow when end issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, animation

I am using jquery animate function to animate my text and also want to rotate text if degree passed or 0 degree means no rotation so I have used following code:

```
var leftCss = "-"+$('#mydiv').width();
var leftAnt = $('#mydiv').parent().width();
$('#mydiv').each(function () {this.xpos =  leftCss; })
           .animate({  xpos: leftAnt}, {
                duration:10000,
                step: function (now) { 
                   var scaleVal =parseInt( now);
                   $(this).css('transform','rotate(0deg) translateX('+scaleVal+'px) translateY('+$('#mydiv').height()+'px)'); 
                },
            },'linear');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nufafjjs/1/

But it is fast in the middle and slows down when end but I want it with same speed all the time. Don't understand the issue? Also, one more issue is rotated > 90 deg is hide the text from the box.

thanks

Comment: An snippet or Fiddle would be more helpful to answer this.

Comment: okay let me create fiddle!!

Comment: @RohanKumar: Updated!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are passing animate options as second parameter in [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), so the third parameter `'linear'` will make no sense here and hence default `swing` easing is applied to it. So to solve this add `easing:'linear'` in the second options parameter like,

```js
function animateScroll() {
  $(".block").each(function() {
    this.offsetX = '-' + $('.block').width();
  }).animate({
    offsetX: parseInt($('.parent').width())
  }, {
    duration: 10000,
    step: function(now, fx) { //console.log(now)
      var scaleVal = parseInt(now);
      scaleVal += 10;
      $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(0deg) translateX(' + scaleVal + 'px) translateY(0px)');
    },
    complete: function() { //console.log('in complate')
      return animateScroll();
    },
    easing: 'linear' // add easing here
  });
}
animateScroll();
```

```css
.block {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">some content here....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but rotate is not working with width. How to rotate?

Comment: for 90deg it is not starting from top : 0

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution only with css animations.
You need `animation-timing-function:linear` to keep animation at constant speed.
You can change speed of animation by changing `animation-duration` value.

```css
.block {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  font-size:50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  
  //or just a shorthand
  //animation: example 6s linear infinite;
}
  
@keyframes example {
  from {transform:translateX(-500px);}
  to {transform:translateX(500px);}
}
.parent{
  width:500px;
  height: 50px;
  border:solid; 
  position: absolute;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="block">some content here....</div>
```